# Swift 2 / OSX 10.11 / Xcode 7.0.1 / Cocoapods 0.38.2 Can't Build Project

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, cocoapods

I have the release versions of El Capitan, Xcode 7, and Cocoapods and am getting an issue when I try to build my sample app for this pod:
https://github.com/AttilaTheFun/SwiftToolKit

The error I get is:

```
ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.xctest/Info.plist Tests/Info.plist
    cd /Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    builtin-infoPlistUtility /Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example/Tests/Info.plist -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -o /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.xctest/Info.plist

PhaseScriptExecution Check\ Pods\ Manifest.lock /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Script-707B1AF3217AA4B9513CA00A.sh
    cd /Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example
    /bin/sh -c /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Script-707B1AF3217AA4B9513CA00A.sh

CompileSwiftSources normal x86_64 com.apple.xcode.tools.swift.compiler
    cd /Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swiftc -incremental -module-name SwiftToolKit_Tests -Onone -D COCOAPODS -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk -target x86_64-apple-ios8.3 -g -module-cache-path /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options -enable-testing -I /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -parse-as-library -c -j8 /Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example/Tests/Tests.swift -output-file-map /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests-OutputFileMap.json -parseable-output -serialize-diagnostics -emit-dependencies -emit-module -emit-module-path /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests.swiftmodule -Xcc -I/Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/swift-overrides.hmap -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/SwiftToolKit_Tests-generated-files.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/SwiftToolKit_Tests-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/SwiftToolKit_Tests-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/all-product-headers.yaml -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/SwiftToolKit_Tests-project-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include -Xcc -I/Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/DerivedSources/x86_64 -Xcc -I/Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/DerivedSources -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -emit-objc-header -emit-objc-header-path /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests-Swift.h -Xcc -working-directory/Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example -Xfrontend -serialize-debugging-options

Ditto /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/DerivedSources/SwiftToolKit_Tests-Swift.h /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests-Swift.h
    cd /Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/ditto -rsrc /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests-Swift.h /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/DerivedSources/SwiftToolKit_Tests-Swift.h

Ditto /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftdoc /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests.swiftdoc
    cd /Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/ditto -rsrc /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests.swiftdoc /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftdoc

Ditto /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests.swiftmodule
    cd /Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/ditto -rsrc /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests.swiftmodule /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.swiftmodule/x86_64.swiftmodule

Ld /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.xctest/SwiftToolKit_Tests normal x86_64
    cd /Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.3
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch x86_64 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator9.0.sdk -L/Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -mios-simulator-version-min=8.3 -bundle_loader /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Example.app/SwiftToolKit_Example -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -framework SwiftToolKit -framework XCTest -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphonesimulator -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests.swiftmodule -weak_framework Pods_SwiftToolKit_Tests -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SwiftToolKit_Tests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.xctest/SwiftToolKit_Tests

GenerateDSYMFile /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.xctest.dSYM /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.xctest/SwiftToolKit_Tests
    cd /Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/dsymutil /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.xctest/SwiftToolKit_Tests -o /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.xctest.dSYM

PhaseScriptExecution Embed\ Pods\ Frameworks /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Script-B1DCFB915331FD5EFCE1096D.sh
    cd /Users/Logan/Documents/Development/Services/SwiftToolKit/Example
    /bin/sh -c /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Intermediates/SwiftToolKit.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.build/Script-B1DCFB915331FD5EFCE1096D.sh

mkdir -p /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.xctest/Frameworks
rsync -av --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Pods-SwiftToolKit_Tests/SwiftToolKit.framework" "/Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.xctest/Frameworks"
building file list ... done

sent 93 bytes  received 20 bytes  226.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
error: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/otool: can't open file: /Users/Logan/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SwiftToolKit-akzjacxhtospytamwfcyrphcsoar/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SwiftToolKit_Tests.xctest/Frameworks/SwiftToolKit.framework/SwiftToolKit (No such file or directory)
```

I am not sure what it is looking for - the SwiftToolKit framework compiles just fine. Any suggestions?